# Is (or are) there a standard trait for XML and JSON serializable objects in Scala/Lift?

Tags: xml, json, scala, lift

In my Lift projects I use a trait of my own:

```
import scala.xml.Node
import net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JValue

trait Serializable {
  def toXml : Node
  def toJson : JValue
}
```

Am I not "reinventing a bycicle"? Isn't it there a common standard library trait for this?

Answer (score 0):

Record has an asJSON method, and you can use net.liftweb.json.XML to turn json into xml.  Do you not want to mixin Record because it is too much for your objects?